# Using CSS3 in a PrestaShop invoice

Tags: php, prestashop, tcpdf, prestashop-1.6

I'm doing the restyling of invoices in a eCommerce PrestaShop (1.6.1.14 version), unfortunately does not recognize me some instructions in CSS3.
The version of tcpdf 5.9.179 is instead that of smarty is 3.1.19.
What are the best practices to be able to use the CSS3?

Comment: TCPD has very limited CSS support. There are some plugins for it, some of them deal with extending CSS support, and writing a plugin for TCPDF is not that difficult, provided you invest some time in studying PDF specification.

Comment: I solved it by replacing TCPDF with dompdf.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498044/prestashop-libraries-replacement/38554722#38554722