# PrestaShop libraries replacement

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, dompdf

I use PrestaShop 1.6.1.4 and I want to change the library tcpdf with dompdf.

I use this form for creating invoices.

What are the best practices for a library exchange?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created inside override the tools folder and I put us dompdf-master found here https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf.

Instead inside override/classes/pdf i copied PDFGenerator.php, there is in classes/pdf.

In PDFGenerator.php add:

```
require_once('/../override/tools/dompdf-master/dompdf/Dompdf.php');
require_once('/../override/tools/dompdf-master/autoload.inc.php');
include('/../override/tools/dompdf-master/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
```

The class becomes:

```
class PDFGenerator extends DOMPDF
```

Eliminates the render() function and replace it with:

```
public function render($filename, $display = true)
{
    if (empty($filename)) {
        throw new PrestaShopException('Missing filename.');
    }

    $html = $this->header.$this->content.$this->footer;
    //die($html);    

    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('A4','potrait');
    $options->set('enable_css_float',true);
    $options->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF($options);
    $dompdf->load_html($html);

    $dompdf->render();

    $dompdf->stream($filename);
}
```

Then i deleted cache/class_index.php